# Diagonal da matriz em java

Tags: java, matriz

Primeiramente, gostaria de informar que sou novo aqui no site, e se por acaso minha pergunta ficou sem informação ou mal organizada por favor falem.

Estava tentando resolver essa pergunta:

[image: Fotografia do exercício]

Consegui desenvolver este código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Matriz1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N = ler.nextInt();



    int i, j, m[][] = new int[N][N];

    // Ler matriz   
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
      //informa linha
      System.out.printf("Informe os elementos %da. linha:\n", (i+1));
          for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            //informa qual numero deve se colocar
            System.out.printf("m[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            m[i][j] = ler.nextInt();
          }
      // salta linha para n ficar confuso
      System.out.printf("\n");
    }
```

Porém não consigo entender como irei tirar a diferenças das diagonais da matriz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ficou assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matriz1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = ler.nextInt();

        int matriz[][] = new int[n][n];

        // Lê a matriz.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Informa a linha.
            System.out.printf("Informe os elementos %da. linha:\n", (i + 1));
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                // Informa qual número deve se colocar.
                System.out.printf("m[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                matriz[i][j] = ler.nextInt();
            }
            // Salta linha para não ficar confuso.
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

        // Obtém a soma das diagonais.
        int somaDiagonal1 = 0, somaDiagonal2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            somaDiagonal1 += matriz[i][i];
            somaDiagonal2 += matriz[n - 1 - i][i];
        }

        // Calcula a diferença das somas.
        int diferenca = somaDiagonal1 - somaDiagonal2;
        if (diferenca < 0) diferenca *= -1;

        // Exibe o resultado.
        System.out.printf("A difereça da soma das diagonais é %d.", diferenca);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado ,deu certo !

Answer (score 2):

Não sou nada experiente em java, mas imaginei que com isso poderia te ajudar, adicione isso ao seu código:

```
int D = 0; // soma dos números da diangonal 2

for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  D += m[i][i];
}

int d = 0; // somas dos números da diangonal 1

for (i=0; i<N; i++) {

  for (j=N-1; j>=0; j--) {
     d += m[i][j];
     break;
  }
}
int df = d - D; // resultado da diferença da soma dos números das diagonais (o que voce quer :D)
```

Uma vez fiz algo parecido em javascript, usei a mesma lógica, caso algo dê errado, avise por favor.

Comment: o D está dando certo porem  d me parece que não está diminuindo o j porque no exemplo

11 02 04
04 05 06
10 08 -12

D=4
d=-2

acho que d está fazendo 4+6+-12

ps:coloquei 0 nos numeros menos que 10 para facilitar a leitura não coloquei assim no programa